# Filename not being passed to main

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an app and I have a file type associated with it. When I doubleclick the file it opens my app but the filename/path never gets passed to my app. It does work if I drag the file over the icon, however. Here is the main():

```
    static void Main(string[] filenames)
    {
        Form1 form = null;

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        form = new Form1();
        if (filenames != null && filenames.Length > 0)
            form.FileName = filenames[0];
        Application.Run(form);
    }
```

filenames.length comes up 0 every time (unless I drag/drop the file onto the app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData
```

is also is a string[]

Comment: Unless you're using ClickOnce to start the application, I fail to see how this will help an ordinary, locally installed application.

Comment: I am using ClickOnce actually so I will look into this.

Comment: What I meant to say, is "when you're using ClickOnce to start an application **by clicking a url in your browser**". In this case, the browser can pass additional prameters as part of the url to your program, which you can get at through this API. See my answer for what's probably going on here.

Comment: what I ended up with was this:
if (filenames == null || filenames.Length == 0)
                filenames = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData
                    .Select(s => new Uri(s).LocalPath).ToArray();

Comment: Ruben, I know it's for ClickOnce but I wasn't sure in what other situations this applies. Still have to find that out. But that's why I said 'try'.

Answer (score 2):

Does your file association contain a %1 or "%L" as part of the command line? This is required to pass the file name to your application. ("%L" means the full, long file name, %1 is the shortened 8.3 file name.)

The reason your application does receive the file name when you drop the file *on the application icon*, is because Windows doesn't use a file association here. In fact, it will work for any program, with and without file association. In these cases it guesses that you probably want to start the application with the file's name as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have %1 or %L in file association settings to "tell" Windows Explorer to pass filename to your application when double-clicked on the file. An example: 
http://hypography.com/forums/tutorials-and-how-tos/15876-windows-file-association-tutorial.html